# Unauthorized with ValidAudiences IdentityServer4

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 set up on ASP.NET Core 2.0 and everything was working until I tried to add multiple valid audiences to an api.

Here is the Config where the api resources are defined:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<
        new ApiResource(){
            Name ="wallets.api",
            Description ="Wallets API",
            Scopes = new List<Scope>(){
                new Scope() {
                    Name = "wallets.api",
                    DisplayName="Wallets API"
                },
                new Scope()
                {
                    Name="all.api"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I added the scope "all.api" because I want to request a token valid on multiple apis with just one scope instead of a list.

On the Wallets API Startup.cs :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Authority = Configuration["JWTSettings:JWTIssuer"];
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidAudiences = new List<string>
        {
            "wallets.api",
            "all.api"
        },
        ValidateAudience = true
    };
});
```

I tried to authenticate on Postman by using the scope "wallets.api" and received the access token and I can send requests to the Wallets API with no problems.

However if I change it to all.api, when i send requests to Wallets API I get 401 Unauthorized.

This is the client configuration

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{

    return new List<Client>
    {

        // resource owner password grant client
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mobile",
            AllowedGrantTypes = new List<string>(){"password"},

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes = {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                "wallets.api",
                "all.api"
            },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>(){"http://localhost:5000"}
        }
    };
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

What's interesting is that the token requested with wallets.api scope has both aud and scope set to wallets.api

```
 "aud": [
    "http://identity.api/resources",
    "wallets.api"
 ],
 "scope": [
    "wallets.api"
  ]
```

However, the token requested with all.api scope, has only the scope, and in the aud there is identity.api instead of all.api

```
 "aud": [
     "http://identity.api/resources",
     "identity.api"
  ],
  "scope": [
      "all.api"
  ],
```

EDIT:

Now I tried to request a token with both wallets.api and all.api, and I saw all.api is only present in scopes

```
 "aud": [
     "http://identity.api/resources",
     "identity.api",
     "wallets.api"
 ],
 "scope": [
     "all.api",
     "wallets.api"
 ]
```

I feel like I misunderstood scopes and audiences. Does all.api need to be an api resource as well? It looks like only api resources can be an audience

Comment: Decode the access token you receive from IdentityServer on jwt.io. The scope might not be in the token. Did you request the new scope in your token request?

Comment: Yes the scope is in the token, as i said when I request the "wallets.api" scope in the token request It works. But when i request the new scope, I stil receive the token with the scope inside, but the Wallets API returns Unauthorized